How to parse nested json using json_extract_path_text in amazon redshift
{"topics": ["Fintech", "Artificial Intelligence", "Market Research & Consumer Insights"],
 "companies": [{"name": "TKO Group", "idCbiEntity": 1091583}, {"name": "All Elite Wrestling", "idCbiEntity": 1058641},
 {"name": "New Japan Pro Wrestling", "idCbiEntity": 276499}]}

From this, I want extract "name" in the companies tag in to a single column
select 
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT('{"topics": ["Fintech", "Artificial Intelligence", "Market Research & Consumer Insights"],
 "companies": [{"name": "TKO Group", "idCbiEntity": 1091583}, {"name": "All Elite Wrestling", "idCbiEntity": 1058641},
 {"name": "New Japan Pro Wrestling", "idCbiEntity": 276499}]}','companies', 'name',true);

However, I keep getting null values as result

Redshift has 2 functions for parsing JSON strings - JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT() and JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT().  You need the second to extract elements from JSON arrays which you have in your string.
You need to do something like:
with input as (
select '{"topics": ["Fintech", "Artificial Intelligence", "Market Research & Consumer Insights"], "companies": [{"name": "TKO Group", "idCbiEntity": 1091583}, {"name": "All Elite Wrestling", "idCbiEntity": 1058641}, {"name": "New Japan Pro Wrestling", "idCbiEntity": 276499}]}'::text as txt
)
select 
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT( 
    JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT(
        JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(txt, 'companies'),
      0),
'name') as result
FROM input;

The issue with this is that you only get one array element.  Now you could cross join with some index numbers and get all the "names" but there is a easier and built-in way to do this.  Convert you string to a super data type with the JSON_PARSE() function.
with input as (
    select JSON_PARSE('{"topics": ["Fintech", "Artificial Intelligence", "Market Research & Consumer Insights"], "companies": [{"name": "TKO Group", "idCbiEntity": 1091583}, {"name": "All Elite Wrestling", "idCbiEntity": 1058641}, {"name": "New Japan Pro Wrestling", "idCbiEntity": 276499}]}') as sup
)
select sup, c.name as result
FROM input i, i.sup.companies c;

This is called array unnesting and you can read up on it at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html
